# Custom Taxonomy Sort For a Custom Query

Tags: customization, sort

I am trying to custom sort taxonomies on a custom query I have written for one of my website

I cannot use any custom plugin as I have tried and they do not work with my current setup.

```
add_action('init', 'ecommerce_create_post_type', 1);
function ecommerce_create_post_type() {

// Create new Latest-News custom post type
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Products', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Product'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
'new_item' => __('New Products'),
'view_item' => __('View Products'),
'search_items' => __('Search Products'),
'not_found' =>  __('No Products found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Products found in Trash'), 
'_builtin' =>  false, 
'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'show_ui' => true, 
'query_var' => true,
'sort' => true,
'register_meta_box_cb' => 'icom_meta_boxes',
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'products',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => true,
'menu_position' => 20,
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields','excerpt'),
'menu_icon' => ICOMMERCE_DIR.'/images/cart.png'
  ); 
  register_post_type('products',$args);  

// Product categories, is heirarchical and can use permalinks
$labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Categories'),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Product Categories'),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Product Category'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product Category'),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Product Category'),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product Category'),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Product Category Name')
        );

register_taxonomy( 'icomcat', 'products', array(
    'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'product-category',
    'with_front' => false,
    'sort' => true,
    ),
    'labels' => $labels,
) );
}
```

using the following code , I am fetching the latest products

```
  <?php
global $wpdb;
$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;
$latest_products = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT a.term_id, a.name 
  FROM ".$prefix."terms a,".$prefix."term_taxonomy b 
  WHERE b.parent=".$prodcatid." 
  and a.term_id=b.term_id 
  and b.taxonomy='icomcat' 
  order by a.name desc"); 
if ( count( $latest_products ) > 0 ) {$count=0;
echo '<div class="clear3"> </div><div class="text12">  <h3> <a> <?php $current_category = single_cat_title("", false); ?></a></h3></div><div class="clear3"> </div><div id="cateogybox">';
    foreach ( $latest_products as $latest_product ) { $count=$count+1; 
?>
```

I am trying to sort these results using the date field. as you can see I am firing

```
$latest_products = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT a.term_id, a.name 
  FROM ".$prefix."terms a,".$prefix."term_taxonomy b 
  WHERE b.parent=".$prodcatid." 
  and a.term_id=b.term_id 
  and b.taxonomy='icomcat' 
  order by a.name desc");
```

but my results are not sorted by date.

Comment: What date field? Your queries are pulling from the `terms` and the `term_taxonomy` tables only and [neither of those have a "date" field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_terms) nor do you even attempt to `ORDER BY` such a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'icomcat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($prodcatid)
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how it will sort by date ? I tried using it but no visible difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the get_posts() function the default will be sort by date.

```
$latest_products = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'products',
));

foreach($latest_products as $product) {
    print "{$product->post_title}<br>\n";
}
```

You also need to be aware that wordpress will automatically do a similar query when you put ?post_type=products in your url.

Comment: Only gets one post ? Also this broke the whole layout template.

Comment: <?php

$latest_products = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'     => 1,
 'taxonomy' => 'icomcat',
    'post_type'       => 'products',
));

if ( count( $latest_products ) > 0 ) {$count=0;
echo '<div class="clear3"> </div><div class="text12">  <h3> <a> <?php $current_category = single_cat_title("", false); ?></a></h3></div><div class="clear3"> </div><div id="cateogybox">';
    foreach ( $latest_products as $latest_product ) { $count=$count+1; 
?>                           <h2> <a><?php echo $latest_product->name; ?></a></h2> doesnt seem to work

Comment: 'numberposts'=>-1 (not 1) That means you get all posts.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Even with -1 it is only giving me 1 post.